# Plotly Dash -Disable button while loading Dash with dcc.Loading

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash

I am trying to disable a button while processing a request in dash.
Currently I have this ([Display loading symbol while waiting for a result with plot.ly Dash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54439548/display-loading-symbol-while-waiting-for-a-result-with-plot-ly-dash)) implemented. I am trying to figure out how can I disable a button while a long query is on going.

Here are the logics that I tried:

## Logic 1: (I am receiving Circular Dependecy error)

- callack 01:

  - input: button n_click
  - input: DIV last updated (if DIV children populated, set button disabled to false)
  - output: button disabled (if Button no_click set to true)
- Callback 02:

  - input button n_click
  - output DIV last-updated

## Logic 2: (error due same output for both CBs)

- Callback 01:

  - Input Button n_click
  - output Button disabled
  - output last-update
- Callback 02:

  - Input last-update children
  - Output Button disabled

I also tried dcc.Loading with the button. I can activate the spinner, but the button keeps enabled.

```
html.Div([dbc.Button("load data", id="but-data", className="mr-2", disabled=False), dcc.Loading(id="loading-1", type="default", children=html.Div(id="loading-output-1"))]),
```

any suggestion?

Comment: actually a better way to ask that is: how can I change the button state while processing a callback?

Comment: If you want to edit you Question, there's an option for that. Just click "edit" right under your Question.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. I solved it using a global `computing` variable and a children updating callback:

```py
computing = False

#example definition
button = dbc.Button([dbc.Spinner([],id='spinner') ], id ='button', block=True, id = id)
## app code here

<your code>

### callback on click

@app.callback([Output("button",'disabled'),Output("spinner",'children')],Input('button','n_clicks'))
def updatefn(input):
    global computing
    if computing:
        return True,[dbc.Spinner(color="light",size='sm')]

    else:
       computing = True
       do something

      # finish
      computing = False
       return False,[]
```

This method does not execute the function again, and disables the button for the duration of the computation.

Comment: I tried this approach and only the spinner works - the disabled state doesn't update for some reason. I couldn't declare the button the same way as you did and ended up doing this: `gobutton = html.Div([dbc.Button("Go!",id="submit-button-state-go-run-query",n_clicks=0,disabled=False,style={'width': c.input_width,'margin-bottom': '10px'},),dbc.Spinner(html.Div(id="spinner")),])`