# How to set type and color properties of Dash Loading dcc.Loading with CSS

Tags: css, plotly, plotly-dash

When using dcc.Loading() in a Dash App one can set the type i.e. 'cube', or 'dots' as well as the color - [documentation](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/loading)

```
dcc.Loading(
    children=[html.Div(id='test-div')],
    type='dot', 
    color='hotpink'
)
```

What I would like to know is how to set these in the CSS rather than with inline styling to avoid having to change every loading component in all apps if I want to change the spinner or colour scheme.

So far, [with help from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54439548/display-loading-symbol-while-waiting-for-a-result-with-plot-ly-dash) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68188107/how-to-add-create-a-custom-loader-with-dash-plotly), I have been able to access the dash-spinner class in the CSS. But whilst I can change the background-color and size I can't work out how to fix the type or the foreground colour.

```
.dash-spinner {
  background-color: black;
  color: hotpink;
  type: cube;
}

.dash-spinner * {
  display: none !important;
}
```

This CSS seems to act on the background colour but not the spinner or the colour of the spinner.

Thank you

Comment: Please refer to the [official reference](https://dash.plotly.com/external-resources) for an explanation of local CSS.

Comment: Thanks @r-beginners, but I’m not clear which part you are referring to in the docs? My issue isn’t using local CSS, I have locally working CSS and have found the class name - but can’t get the CSS to act as I would like.